# how to debug windows service by visual studio 2017

Tags: debugging, service

I create a windows service and install on another server.
my problem is I cant is install visual studio on the server and i need to debug the service . 
I now how to debug service on my computer but i do not know how to debug service when service is on another machine.
I can not install and debug service on my computer because my computer have not the server Conditions.
thank you for help and excuse me for grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=475). Resource says. As you have mentioned in comment that you have installed it. Please go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging).

> The Remote Debugger Installation is intended for computers without
>   Visual Studio in order to debug applications executing on these
>   computers. A full installation of Visual Studio 2010 with remote
>   debugging support must be used to connect to these components.

Comment: I Installed the remote debugger on the server and in  permission  menu gave permission to my user . but in visual studio i cant see the service on " debug>attach to process (connection type : remote)"

Comment: I have updated my answer. If that couldn't help we will see